# graphic visualization of correlation between samples

Tags: r, correlation

```
s1
     name    tis1    tis2    tis3     tis4    tis5     tis6    tis7    tis8     tis9    tis10      tis11    tis12
    S1       0       0       0       12.1    29.2      1.9    0.45     0.2     17.0    0.4        0.7      0.1


s2            
        name    tis1    tis2    tis3     tis4    tis5     tis6    tis7    tis8     tis9    tis10      tis11    tis12
        S2       1       2       0.4       14.1    9.2      1.8    0.7     0.9     7.0    0.3        0.7      0.3
```

I would to plot them to visualize their degree of correlation.
There is a way to do it?

Comment: What does tis**n** represent? Could this data be reshaped to a single dataframe with 2 columns: s1 and s2? If so once, you create the dataframe then you can apply the cor function: something like ```cor(df$s1, df$s2)```

Comment: I calculated the correlation doing cor(S1, S2)... I would represent their degree of correlation with a plot

Comment: Not sure I follow. We can plot a scatter plot if S1 and S2 if they are a separate columns in a df. This would not show correlation per say, but you could kind of eyeball if there is strong correlation in some cases.

Comment: I say, I was thinking to create two heatmap to compare values...